# For loop loops only 3 times

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, queue

Why for loops only 3 times ?

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Dodany element kolejki: " << i << std::endl;
    queue.Enqueue(i);
}
```

The for loop always breaks when i is equal to 3.
And here is code for Queue class:

```
#ifndef QUEUE_H
#define QUEUE_H

#include "Node.h"
#include <stdexcept>

template<class T>
class Queue
{
public:
    Queue()
    {
        this->FirstElement = nullptr;
        this->LastElement = nullptr;
    }

    void Enqueue(T value)
    {
        if (0 == Size())
        {
            FirstElement = new Node<T>(value);
            LastElement = FirstElement;
        }
        else
        {
            LastElement->Previous = new Node<T>(value);
            LastElement = LastElement->Previous;
        }
    }

    T Dequeue()
    {
        if (0 == Size())
        {
            throw std::out_of_range("Out of range ! Empty stack !");
        }

        T element(FirstElement->Value);

        if (nullptr != FirstElement->Previous)
        {
            Node<T>* temp = FirstElement->Previous;
            delete FirstElement;
            FirstElement = temp;
        }
        else
        {
            delete FirstElement;
            FirstElement = nullptr;
            LastElement = nullptr;
        }

        return element;
    }

    int Size()
    {
        int queueSize = 0;
        Node<T>* element = FirstElement;

        if (nullptr != FirstElement)
        {
            while (nullptr != FirstElement->Previous)
            {
                ++queueSize;
            }

            ++queueSize; //Uwzglednienie ostatniego elementu, ktory nie jest policzony w petli
        }

        return queueSize;
    }

private:
    Node<T>* FirstElement;
    Node<T>* LastElement;
};
#endif // !QUEUE_H
```

And code for Node structure:

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

template<class T>
struct Node
{
public:
    Node(T value)
    {
        this->Previous = nullptr;
        this->Value = value;
    }

    Node<T>* Previous;
    T Value;
};
#endif // !NODE_H
```

And here is output:

```
Dodany element kolejki: 0
Dodany element kolejki: 1
Dodany element kolejki: 2
```

When i delete the call of the enqueue method for loops 10 times. There is no warning from compilator or exception thrown or any other error of any kind. It's just loops 3 times for some reason.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program does not stop at loop iteration 3, but rather gets hung after 3 iterations.
This is most likely due to the Queue::Size() function that seems to enter an infinite loop.

I think you meant Size to be something like:

```
int Size()
{
    int queueSize = 0;
    Node<T>* element = FirstElement;

    if (nullptr != FirstElement)
    {
        while (nullptr != element->Previous)
        {
            element = element->Previous;
            ++queueSize;
        }
        ++queueSize;
    }
    return queueSize;
}
```